# UI Picker item source list should not appear on clicking "ok" in Display Alert

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am working on a Xamarin app, there is a screen where I need to select a url and on selecting, an alert shows : Url changed successfully. On clicking ok, it is displaying the list of all urls which is not required:

My .xaml looks like this:

```
<ContentView.Content>
        <Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" RowSpacing="10">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="35" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Label Grid.Row="0" Text="{translate:Translate Change_Server_URL}" FontSize="Small"/>

            <Frame HeightRequest="35" Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource EntryFramStyle}">
                <Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <rendres:CustomPicker
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        HasBorder="False"
                        x:Name="URLPicker"
                        SelectedIndexChanged="URLPicker_SelectedIndexChanged"
                        Margin="5,0,5,0"
                        VerticalOptions="Center"
                         >
                    </rendres:CustomPicker>
                    <!--<Label Text="&#xf078;" TextColor="{StaticResource FontTitleIconColor}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" VerticalOptions="Center"  FontFamily="{StaticResource FontAwesome}">

                    </Label>-->
                </Grid>


            </Frame>

        </Grid>
    </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

and my .cs file looks like this:

```
    public partial class ChangeServerUrl : ContentView
        {
            List<string> urlItems = new List<string>()
            {

                "http://divcraft-001-site4.com/",
                "https://lcdpbe.azurewebs.net",
                "http://192.168.0.14:8077"
            };
            private bool handleSelect = false;

            public ChangeServerUrl ()
            {
                InitializeComponent ();
                URLPicker.ItemsSource = urlItems;
                URLPicker.SelectedItem = Preferences.Get(Constants.PreferenceKeys.SERVER_BASE, Constants.PreferenceKeys.SERVER_BASE);

            }
            private void URLPicker_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

          if(handleSelect == true) { 

                    Preferences.Set(Constants.PreferenceKeys.SERVER_BASE, URLPicker.SelectedItem.ToString());
                    RestLayer.RestService.Instance.ChangeClientBase(URLPicker.SelectedItem.ToString());
                    App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("", AppResources.Server_Base_Changed_Message, AppResources.OK);
                }
                else
                {
                    handleSelect = true;
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

The above code has a Picker which has three urls. Once I select one of them, alert should come and then click on Ok the list should not appear. I am not sure how to get this working, I need the alert in my code. 
[image: upon selecting one of the url from list[![This list should not come after clicking ok]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9Ful.png)

Answer (score 0):

No need for handleSelect flag. You can use async await method.

```
    private async void URLPicker_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Preferences.Set(Constants.PreferenceKeys.SERVER_BASE, URLPicker.SelectedItem.ToString());
        RestLayer.RestService.Instance.ChangeClientBase(URLPicker.SelectedItem.ToString());
        await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("", AppResources.Server_Base_Changed_Message, AppResources.OK);

    }
```

Comment: I did same thing, it shows the Alert on click of Settings. I want only want alert when the value is changed

Comment: Then try to include async await and check

Comment: Async await. I am not aware how to do that. The above one I tried, not working

Comment: The same issue you are facing in android also?

Comment: Can you try URLPicker.Unfocus(); in selectionchanged event?

Comment: The issue is coming only in iOS, my code is working fine in andoird.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195199/discussion-between-venkydhana-and-sver).

Answer (score 0):

Take some action on user `userChoice` in the Alert dialog:

```
bool userChoice = await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("title", "message", "accept", "cancel");

if (userChoice == true) // user accepted; do not display picker or picker not visible?
else // user cancelled
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your display alert is being called on a background thread. You have to display the Alert on the main UI thread, when it is called in response to an async event. So try to enclose it in Device.InokeOnMainThread

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread (() => {
  App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("", AppResources.Server_Base_Changed_Message, AppResources.OK);
});
```